# Python simulation practice TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

I found source code on internet and was changing part of it as practice and learning (I didn't mean to do any Plaigirism or other stuffs). The problem happened in method `_generate_empty_noise_grid(self, map_width, map_height)`.

I want to do create a random sequence of `0`s and `1`s only in range of `y < 20`: but my source code did not work.

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import time


class MapGrid():
    def __init__(self, map_width, map_height):

        # set map values
        self.map_width = map_width
        self.map_height = map_width

        # generate outside rooms
        self.outside_terrain_grid = self._generate_empty_noise_grid(self.map_width, self.map_height)

    def _generate_empty_noise_grid(self, map_width, map_height):

        new_map_grid = [] # create our new list
        for x in range(map_width):
            new_map_grid.append([]) # add our columns to the array
            for y in range(map_height):
                if y > 20: 
                    new_map_grid[x].append(random.choice([0,1])) # fill in our rows
                else: 
                    new_map_grid[x].append([0])


        return new_map_grid

    def _generate_outside_terrain(self, empty_outside_terrain_grid, number_of_generations):
        '''
        creates a bubble effect with cellular automaton
        '''
        grid = empty_outside_terrain_grid
        number_of_generations = number_of_generations

        for x in range(number_of_generations):
            next_grid = []
            for column_index, column in enumerate(grid):
                next_column = []
                next_grid.append(next_column)
                for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):

                    top_left = grid[column_index - 1][tile_index - 1]
                    top_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index - 1]

                    if top_mid == 1: 
                        next_cell = 1 
                    elif top_mid == 0: 
                        next_cell = 0 

                    next_column.append(next_cell)

            grid = next_grid

        return next_grid




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # general map stats
    map_width = 140
    map_height = 30

    # start with one generation
    tile_size = 8

    map_grid = MapGrid(map_width, map_height)
    #print map_grid.outside_terrain_grid

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((map_width * tile_size,map_height * tile_size))

    one_tile = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
    one_tile.fill((0,0,0))
    zero_tile = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
    zero_tile.fill((255,255,255))
    colors = {0: zero_tile, 1: one_tile}

    background = pygame.Surface((map_width * tile_size,map_height * tile_size))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    first_gen = True
    timer = 12

    running = True
    while running == True:
        clock.tick(3)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        if first_gen:
            themap = map_grid.outside_terrain_grid
        else:
            themap = map_grid._generate_outside_terrain(themap, 1)

        for column_index, column in enumerate(themap):
            for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):
                screen.blit(colors[tile], (tile_index * tile_size, column_index * tile_size))

        pygame.display.flip()

        if first_gen:
            timer -= 1
            if timer < 0:
                first_gen = False

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please share the stack trace. This will indicate which line the error occurred on.

Comment: What's the point of the last line `number_of_generations = number_of_generations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is improperly formed. The first couple cells of the first row looks like this:

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]...
```

But it should look like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0....
```

The problem is in `_generate_empty_noise_grid`. You are adding lists when you should be adding integers.

```
else: 
    new_map_grid[x].append([0])
```

This should be

```
else: 
    new_map_grid[x].append(0)
```

Comment: @jdubKim, Glad to hear it :-) Feel free to accept my answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: I just got another problem here. Can I ask you something personally?

Answer (score -1):

not sure if I understand your question but you say you want: "What I wanted to do was create random sequence of 0 and 1 only in range of y < 20"

however in your code I find:

```
for y in range(map_height):
    if y > 20: 
        new_map_grid[x].append(random.choice([0,1])) # fill in our row
    else: 
        new_map_grid[x].append([0])
```

So, if I'm not misunderstanding everything, shouldn't that be y<20 ?

Thus:

```
for y in range(map_height):
    if y < 20: 
        new_map_grid[x].append(random.choice([0,1])) # fill in our row
    else: 
        new_map_grid[x].append([0])
```

Cheers